# Pandas: create column based on whether value exists in differents columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to create a new column based on these conditions:

- if column 1 isn't empty then new column value is 1
- if column 2 isn't empty then new column then value is 100
- if both columns aren't empty then new column value is 101

Is there a better way how to do this? Thx

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', np.nan, 100], ['b', 20, np.nan], ['c', 30, 300], ['d', np.nan, np.nan]])


df['is_1'] =  np.where(df[1].notnull(), 1, 0)
df['is_2'] =  np.where(df[2].notnull(), 100, 0)
df['sum'] = df['is_1'] + df['is_2']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just note Boolean values translate to `0` / `1` for computations:

```
df['sum'] = df[1].notnull() + df[2].notnull() * 100
```

Comment: Thx! You just saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Very nice solution :)